# What does this cronjob do?

Tags: shell, ssh, cron

I have some sort of learning block for cron, and no matter what I read, I can never get a get understanding of it. I asked for help from my webhost to create a cron job that runs a python script every two hours.

This is what he sent back:

```
0 */2 * * * python /path/to/file.py >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I get that the first bit is saying everyone hour evenly divisible by two, the second part is using python to execute my file, and the rest, I don't really know.

The support guy sent me an email back saying

> That means that stdout and stderr will be redirected nowhere to keep
>   you clean of garbled messages, and command outputs if any (useful and
>   common in cron).
>
> To test script functionality, use the same without redirection.

Which makes sense, because I remember `>>` being used in the command prompt to write output to files. I still don't get two things though. First, what does `2>&1` do? And second, by redirection, is he talking about sending the output to `/dev/null`? If it didn't go there, and I did want to confirm it was working, where would it go?

Comment: Please read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor (this will explain the 0,1,2) Also, if you want to see the output redirect to a file, eg: /tmp/somefile.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 represents the `stderr` stream, and it's saying to redirect it to same place that stream 1 (`stdout`) was directed, which is `/dev/null` (sometimes referred to as the "bit bucket").

If you didn't want the output to go to `/dev/null`, you could put, for example, a filename there, and the output of stderr and stdout would go there.

Ex:

```
0 */2 * * * python /path/to/file.py >> your_filename 2>&1
```

Finally, the `>>` (as opposed to `>`) means append, so in the case of a filename, the output would be appended instead of overwriting the file. With `/dev/null`, it doesn't matter though since you are throwing away the output anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`2>&1` redirects all error output to the same stream as the standard output (e.g. in your case to `/dev/null` = nowhere)

If you run `python /path/to/file.py` in a console window (e.g. removing the output redirection starting with `>>`) the output will be printed on your console (so you can read it visually)

Note: By default the output of cron jobs will be sent as an e-mail to the user owning the job. For that reason it is very common to always direct standard and error output to `/dev/null`.

Comment: In my experience, `cron` jobs won't have output going to `/dev/console` normally.

Comment: Added short explanation on running the command in a console window (with output visible in the console) and cron job output being sent as e-mail

Answer (score 1):

- `>>` is unnecessary there - /dev/null isn't a real file, it doesn't matter whether you use `>` or `>>`
- `2>&1` means send STDERR to the same place as STDOUT, i.e. /dev/null
- [The man page for cron](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5) explains what it does if you don't have the redirect; in general, it emails the admin with the output.
- If you wanted to check it was working, you'd replace '/dev/null' with an actual file' say '/tmp/log', and check that file. This is why there's a `>>` in the command: when logging to a real file, you want to append each time rather than overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

The `>>` appends standard output to `/dev/null`; the `2>&1` sends file descriptor 2 (standard error) to the same place that file descriptor 1 (standard output) is going.

The append is unusual but not actually harmful; you'd normally just write `>`.  If you were dealing with real files instead of `/dev/null`, the append is probably better, so this reduces the chances of running into problems when you change from `/dev/null` to `/tmp/cron/job.log` or whatever.

Throwing away errors is not necessarily a good idea, but if the command is 'chatty', that output will typically end up in an email to the user whose `cron` job it is.